# Producer & Consumer works on 1 port only

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I only changed the paths to logs and zookeeper-data in configs.

Running zookeeper:

```
    zookeeper-server-start.bat D:\__programs\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Running kafka:

```
    kafka-server-start.bat D:\__programs\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\config\server.properties
```

Running consumer:

```
    kafka-console-consumer.bat -bootstrap-server localhost:2181 -topic mytopic
```

Running producer:

```
    kafka-console-producer.bat -broker-list localhost:9092 -topic mytopic
```

So, consumer can only get messages when it's on the same port(9092) with a producer.

What's the problem here?

Comment: for `kafka-console-consumer.bat -bootstrap-server` you need to specify kafka server port (9092) instead of zookeeper. and what is wrong that consumer and producer connects to the same Kafka cluster?

Comment: They are different protocol handlers... Websites accept GET (output) and POST (input), for example, same port, so why should Kafka be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumers and producers are clients of Kafka server so they both can use same port as we configured as a client port within server.properties file.

Port is configured within `config/server.properties` file with either one of these parameters

- advertised.listeners
- listeners

Depends on configuration and protocol consumers and producers can use multiple ports.
You can find details of broker parameters [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap server and Broker list, both should point to the same

Since you are producing events on localhost:9092, you should use the same in consumer as below:

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic mytopic

kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopic
```

P.S. *Usually `2181` port is assigned to zookeeper process. And here `localhost:2181` will refer to Zookeeper.*